# How to watch the types in dll?

Tags: dll, types, ironpython

import clr

clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r'E:\MyDocuments\Surface Extension\Samples\test.dll')

But, How to watch the types in the test.dll.

import test

I got :
error: No module named test

Shold I must know the types in the test.dll??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For import you need to know the namespaces or type names if not in a namespace to import them.  But you can do "test = clr.LoadAssemblyFromFileWithPath(...)" which will return an assembly object.  In IronPython assembly objects support dotting through them so you could then access the namespaces/types directly from that object.